# Java - How can I convert an object from my own class to a string in the main class?

Tags: java, string-conversion

So, I made my own class called Guidelines, which will contain some text I want to display in a new window, when a user will press a certain button.

```
public class Guidelines {

    public Guidelines(String buttonName){
        guidelines(buttonName);
    }

    private String guidelines(String buttonName){
        String content = "";
        if (buttonName.equals("norman"))
            content = "Norman is the man!";
        if (buttonName.equals("nielsen"))
            content = "Nielsen is the best!";
        if (buttonName.equals("fitt"))
            content = "Fitt rocks!";
        return content;
    }
}
```

But when I call this class in my main class like this:

```
Guidelines content = new Guidelines("norman");
JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(String.valueOf(content));
```

I don't get the string like `"Norman is the man!"`, but something like `uv.Guidelines@12ce0bf`. I guess there's a problem in converting an object to a string. How can I get the string?

Comment: No need to use valueOf, plus content is already a String. This should work by making your method public: JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(Guidelines.guidelines(buttonName));

Comment: @JeanHenry Actually `content` there is a `Guidelines` (so the `valueOf` is needed, and it will result in the `toString` of the `Guidelines` object being called). It's the `content` local variable within the `guidelines` method that is a string. But one of the two should be named better, to avoid confusion.

Comment: All you need do is just overriding the `toString()` method which will return the string generated by `guidelines()` method.

Comment: @SantiBailors Oh the names got me confused, I didnt' realize he named his Guideline "content" as well, I thought he tried getting the result from his private method. There are multiple solutions but override toString works as well IF he doesn't plan on using for things like logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your code what you are doing is that you are defining a class with a constructor name `Guidelines` which take a string value and you have a method named `guidelines` which returns a String and takes in a string value.

Now when you are creating a object/instance

```
Guidelines content = new Guidelines("norman");
```

it creates an Guidelines object for you and call the method `guidelines(String buttonName)` by passing norman. Now the constructor is being called and the constructor is calling the method but the constructor is not returning you anything. So whenever you are writing

```
Guidelines content = new Guidelines("norman");
```

the reference variable is holding the reference to the object in our case content. if you print a reference variable you will see the `hashCode` of that specific object in you case it is `uv.Guidelines@12ce0bf`.

All you need to is that perform a call to the method `guidelines(String buttonName)` like that and in order to call you must declare the method as public.

```
String buttonName = content.guidelines("norman);
```

and then pass the variable buttonName

```
JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(buttonName);
```

or you can call directly

```
JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(String.valueOf(content.guidelines("norman")));
```

Comment: @Vesna It's because the method is `private`, so it's visible only within its own class. You should make it `public` if you want to call it from outside its own class.

Comment: yes SantiBailors is correct i missed it. you must make the method public in order to call it. If it solved your problem please mark it as answer.

Comment: @SantiBailors Sorry, you're right :) when I make the method public, it works perfectly as well :)

Comment: But I wrote it like this:                                                                       Guidelines content = new Guidelines();
JTextArea textArea = new TextArea(content.guidelines("norman")); without String.valueOf

Comment: @Vesna In that code the `String.valueof()` is not needed because the `guidelines` method returns a string. When you were using `new TextArea(content)` where `content` was not a String, `String.valueof(content)` was needed.

Answer (score 1):

do the **String content** a class field, define a method getContent and do:

```
 JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(Guidelines.getContent());
```

example:

```
 public class Guidelines {
    String content;
    public Guidelines(String buttonName){
        guidelines(buttonName);
    }

    private String guidelines(String buttonName){

        if (buttonName.equals("norman"))
            content = "Norman is the man!";
        if (buttonName.equals("nielsen"))
            content = "Nielsen is the best!";
        if (buttonName.equals("fitt"))
            content = "Fitt rocks!";
        return content;
    }

    public String getContent(){
        return content;
    }
}
```

and then

```
Guidelines content = new Guidelines("norman");
JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(content.getContent());
```

Comment: I can't say JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(content.getContent()); because it does't offer me getContent() when I make a dot.

Comment: @Vesna I think it's a typo, `getContent()` should be `public` instead of `private`.

Answer (score 1):

you can override toString method,

```
public class Guidelines {

    private final String content;

    public Guidelines(String buttonName){
        content = guidelines(buttonName);
    }

    private String guidelines(String buttonName){
        String content = "";
        if (buttonName.equals("norman"))
            content = "Norman is the man!";
        if (buttonName.equals("nielsen"))
            content = "Nielsen is the best!";
        if (buttonName.equals("fitt"))
            content = "Fitt rocks!";
        return content;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return content;
    }
}
```

and then , you can invoke toString method to get the content's value

```html
Guidelines content = new Guidelines("norman");
TextArea textArea = new JTextArea(content.toString());
```

Comment: This works, I just made a few changes, I wrote String content without "private final" and I overrided the string like you said and then in my main method I called JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(String.valueOf(content));

Comment: of course, but taking into account the good coding standard is best coupled with "private final"